# A function to add attributes to a network graph

Tags: r, function, igraph

In the example below I calculate some measures of the graph and insert it as an attribute of the vertex of the graph. I would like to transform this into a function where I inform the graph and it already calculates all these measurements and assigns them as an attribute of the vertex. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
library(igraph)

g_antt_i <- igraph::make_full_graph(10)


V(g_antt_i)$degree <- igraph::degree(g_antt_i)
V(g_antt_i)$cc <- transitivity(g_antt_i, type = "local", weights = NA)
V(g_antt_i)$ccw <- transitivity(g_antt_i, type = "local")
V(g_antt_i)$closeness <- igraph::closeness(g_antt_i, mode="all", weights=NA, normalized=T)
V(g_antt_i)$closenessw <- igraph::closeness(g_antt_i, mode="all", normalized=T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it all wrapped in a function, you could create a named list which you then assign to vertex attributes:

```r
library(igraph)

add_attributes <-function(g) {
  vertex_attr(g) <- list(
     degree     = degree(g),
     cc         = transitivity(g, type = "local", weights = NA),
     ccw        = transitivity(g, type = "local"),
     closeness  = closeness(g, mode  = "all", weights = NA, normalized = TRUE),
     closenessw = closeness(g, mode = "all", normalized = TRUE)
  )
  return(g)
}
```

Testing with your example we have:

```r
g_antt_i <- igraph::make_full_graph(10)

add_attributes(g_antt_i)
#> IGRAPH 2217510 U--- 10 45 -- Full graph
#> + attr: name (g/c), loops (g/l), degree (v/n), cc (v/n), ccw (v/n),
#> | closeness (v/n), closenessw (v/n)
#> + edges from 2217510:
#>  [1] 1-- 2 1-- 3 1-- 4 1-- 5 1-- 6 1-- 7 1-- 8 1-- 9 1--10 2-- 3 2-- 4 2-- 5
#> [13] 2-- 6 2-- 7 2-- 8 2-- 9 2--10 3-- 4 3-- 5 3-- 6 3-- 7 3-- 8 3-- 9 3--10
#> [25] 4-- 5 4-- 6 4-- 7 4-- 8 4-- 9 4--10 5-- 6 5-- 7 5-- 8 5-- 9 5--10 6-- 7
#> [37] 6-- 8 6-- 9 6--10 7-- 8 7-- 9 7--10 8-- 9 8--10 9--10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. `vertex.attribtues` is deprecated in favour of `vertex_attr`. Generally, most igraph functions with dots in their name have new names with underscores.

Answer (score 2):

Since all the attributes you want to add are on vertices, you can use `set_vertex_attr` like below for example

```
g_antt_i %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "degree", value = degree(.)) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "cc", value = transitivity(., type = "local", weights = NA))
```

and for other attributes, you can cumulatively add on.